# Calculate when volume counts are cleared based on daily amount received and daily amount processed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have this data table containing the number of returns per day *(Ret Volume)* and the number of returns that have been processed per day *(Volume Cleared)*.
What I'm after is the date displayed on the right displaying what days returns have been processed.

[image]

For example, on 1st Aug we received 472 returns of which 462 where processed leaving 10 still waiting.
The following day we received 380 returns and processed 370 of these.  The first 10 processed would have been from the previous day, so all returns from the 1st were processed by the 2nd.

My first attempt at a formula is below (transpose is only there so I can check returned values for each day without a #SPILL error):  `=TRANSPOSE(LAMBDA(ReturnedVolume,ClearedVolume,BYROW(ClearedVolume,LAMBDA(ClearedToday,SUM(ReturnedVolume)-SUM(ClearedVolume)>ClearedToday)))($F$3:$F3,$H$3:$H3))`
This always returns FALSE I *think* because for 2nd Aug it's calculating 852-832= 20>370 = FALSE.

Starting to think I can't see the wood for the trees now.

Comment: I don't understand.  *`what days returns have been processed.`* Shouldn't you be returning multiple days? IOW, On 2-Aug you are processing returns from both 1-Aug and 2-Aug. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I was after the last day that returns are processed.   So on 2-Aug the 10 remaining from the 1st are processed and then processing starts on those received on the 2nd.  At the end of the day on the 2nd there's still 20 to be processed which are finished on the 3rd - so the 3rd is the last day that returns from the 2nd are processed.  Hopefully that made sense.

Comment: You need to compare the backlog (852-832=20) with previous Returned Volumes, not Cleared Volumes to get the age of the backlog. Any backlog at the start of a day will always contain items from yesterday. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backlog at the end of any particular day is the difference between the cumulative Returned Volume (RV) and the cumulative Cleared Volume (CV). The backlog at the end of one day is the backlog for the start of the next day. The discussion below considers backlogs at the start of the day.

Note a backlog can never be negative since it is impossible to clear in a day anything more than that day's (start of day) backlog and its RV.

With a FIFO (first-in-first-out) regime, any non-zero start of day backlog will always contain some items from the previous day and might contain items from days before that.

If at the start of today the backlog is non-zero and not greater than yesterday's RV, then the oldest item in the backlog cannot be older than yesterday. If it was then FIFO implies all of yesterday's RV would have to be behind it in the backlog queue at the start of today, leading to the contradiction that the backlog would have to be greater than yesterday's RV. Since this oldest item cannot be from today (because it is in the backlog queue at the start of today), it follows it must be from yesterday.

Similar arguments can be used compare the size of today's start of day backlog with the cumulative RV's counting backwards from (but not including) today.

If the size of the backlog at the start of today is (say) *b* and today is day number *d*, then the backlog's oldest item originated on day *d*-*k* if the total RV between days *d*-*1* and *d*-*k* is greater than or equal to *b* whilst that between *d*-1 and *d*-*k*-1 is less than *b*.

The following expression provides the required solution

```
=LET(
backlog, SUM(B$2:B2) - SUM(C$2:C2),
d, ROW() - 1,
INDEX(
    A$2:A3,
    d - IF(backlog > 0,
           1 + SUM(N(backlog > 
           SCAN(0, INDEX(B$2:B2,SEQUENCE(1,d-1,d-1,-1)),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)))),
           0)
      )
)
```

The formula, which should be applied in the third row of the worksheet and copied downwards, assumes:

- in the definition of `d` in the `LET` that row 1 of the worksheet contains the headers and the dates, RVs and CVs are in rows 2 onwards
- dates are in column `A`, RVs in `B` and CVs in `C`

Note that if wrapping within a `LAMBDA` as in the OP there are 3 ranges in the formula `A$2:A3`, `B$2:B2` and `C$2:C2`. The first of these has an additional cell/row compared to the other two.

In the image below, the backlogs are shown for illustrative purposes but the values shown in the worksheet are not used within the formula.

[image: Solution Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the response @DMM.  I haven't had time to check to see if it works for me yet - bank holiday yesterday and got loads to catch up on today.  I'll get back to you as soon as I can. :)

Comment: When developing the solution, I did develop a single spill formula that produced all the results listed in the Earliest column using the `BYROW()` function. However, that produced incorrect results, so I went with your approach of mixed addressing `B$2:B2`, etc. and a solution based on separate formulas in each cell. To understand why I was getting incorrect results, I posted [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983011). The answer emerged as "use `MAP` rather than `BYROW`. When I get time, I will amend my answer here with a spill formula.

Comment: No need unless you really want to.  The formula is going into a table so will cause an error if it spills.  I made a couple of updates to your formula - wrapped your return formula with N() else the 1st row returns the header for my table. Matched previous days results with current so I can leave duplicate dates blank.  `=LET(BackLog, SUM(F$3:F3) - SUM($H$3:$H3),  d, ROW() - 1, LastCompleteDate, N(INDEX($B$2:B3, d - IF(BackLog > 0, 1 + SUM(N(BackLog > SCAN(0, INDEX(F$3:$F3,SEQUENCE(1,d-1,d-1,-1)),LAMBDA(a,v,a+v)))),0))), IF(IFERROR(MATCH(LastCompleteDate,$J$2:$J2,0),0)>0,0,LastCompleteDate))`

Comment: Then gave the column a custom format of `ddd, dd-mmm-yy;;` so that 0 values don't show.  Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Hmmm, ran into a problem with adding the formula to a table - the last row would be referenced in the formula as `$H$3:$H$6` for example, but it would read H6 as the _last row in the table_ so when I added a new row both the new and previous row would be looking at the _last row in the table_.  Swapped the hard-code reference to an INDEX style which worked, but now getting 0 for every row... even though Evaluate Formula is showing my return is the correct date.  Probably another question if I can figure out how to ask it.

Comment: Think I've understood my 0 problem - If I use the formula in the "Ret Processed" column it's still a circular reference even though I'm stopping before I reach the row containing the formula. 
 `IF(IFERROR(MATCH(LastCompleteDate,$J$2:INDEX([Ret Processed],ROW()-3),0),0)>0`

Answer (score 0):

The spill formula (see my comment to my previous answer) is

```
=LET(
    PD, A2:A10,
    RV, B2:B10,
    CV, C2:C10,
    BL, SCAN(0, VSTACK(0, DROP(RV, -1)), LAMBDA(a, v, a + v)) -
        SCAN(0, VSTACK(0, DROP(CV, -1)), LAMBDA(a, v, a + v)),
    seq, SEQUENCE(COUNT(PD) - 1, 1, 2, 1),
    MAP(seq,
        LAMBDA(d,
            INDEX(PD, d -
                IF(INDEX(BL, d) = 0, 0,
                    1 + SUM(N(INDEX(BL, d) >
                            SCAN(0,
                                INDEX(RV,SEQUENCE(1,d - 1, d - 1, -1)),
                                LAMBDA(a, v, a + v)
                            )))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

This formula is entered against the **second** day. (For the first day it is assumed that the system starts empty with no backlog at the start of day 1.)

Note that within the `LAMBDA` of the `MAP` the `LAMBDA` effectively returns for any day d the date given by `INDEX(PD, d - n)`. An `IF` nested with the `INDEX` determines whether the backlog at start of day d is zero and, if so, n is set to zero. It would be possible to reverse the order of the `INDEX` and `IF` to return just zero (rather than a date) on non-backlog days - the same applies to the non-spill version of the formula in the earlier answer.