# Compute gain/loss of widget purchases/sales using FIFO method, Excel spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a widget that I buy in variable-sized lots at various prices, and sell in variable-sized lots of various prices.  I know how to compute the overall costs, receipts, and profit/loss.  But I need to know (for tax purposes ☹️) the gain/loss of each sale, computed by the FIFO inventory method.  How do you do this in Excel?

Here's an example where I put in the "FIFO Gain/Loss" column by hand (with an "Explanation" column).  It shows the idea, but doesn't exhibit all the edge cases.  (It's an image: I didn't think an uploaded spreadsheet would be allowed.)

[image: FIFO example]

I'm looking for a relatively straightforward solution - e.g., columns that I could add and formulas that I could fill the columns with.  Or an add-in that I could use.

- I tried myself but the "recursive" nature of computing the remaining units of each purchase at the time of each sale defeated me
- I looked around the web, couldn't really find anything.  Except [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1805616/302899) on this site which uses `LET` and (nested) `LAMBDA` and `SCAN` and so on and is way beyond my Excel capabilities to understand much less modify to my particular case.
- I didn't invent this FIFO inventory rule.  It's standard in accounting.  So why doesn't Excel support it natively?    (or does it?)

Please don't do anything heroic (like in those answers to the linked question) unless this problem really strikes you and you're going to have fun.  If, as I suspect, there is no reasonably straightforward way to do this in Excel just say so, and then I'll export everything as CSVs and do it in Python.

Comment: if you google "excel fifo inventory", you will find many articles that deal with that. There are also templates that can be downloaded. Some business rules are simply too complex and can't be calculated without using "heroic" approaches.

Comment: TY, @teylyn - I'll do that!

Comment: Why do you need to know the gain/loss for each sale? Income taxes (if that is what you are calculating) is based on aggregate net income, not individual sales. Getting back to the underlying question, when I taught I used to tell my students they need to focus on the quantity flows. After they get that down, it is easier to layer in the pricing. For your spreadsheet I would recomment a conversion to a single transactional style table (instead of one for purchase and one for sales), basically one column showing both quantity inflows/outflows. Hopefully you can take if from there.

Comment: @gns100 - don't you have to account for rise of asset value (e.g., a stock) over its own purchase price?  and if you bought in multiple lots and sold in multiple different lots that all has to be tracked this way (either LIFO or FIFO)?

Comment: @davidbak depends on the tax laws in your country

Comment: Country is USA.  (There's no tag for that in this stack.)

Comment: @davidbak, accounting rules value inventory at the lower of cost or market, so NO you do not make an adjustment for rise of asset value. If you do manage to sell your product for more than you initially thought then that is just added profit. Second LIFO/FIFO are 2 inventory cost flow ASSUMPTIONS developed by accountants a long time ago to simplify keeping track of inventory. It may have no basis in how a company actually manages it's inventory. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to suggest this question be closed as comments do not point to an excel question/issue.

Comment: really?  you don't think a question on how to compute something in Excel is valid even if commenters can't think of a reason that they like?  Ok, go ahead, whatever.

Comment: @gns100 I agree with davidbak ... the question is valid ... usefulness of the computation method is irrelevant to the question